# datatables print not presenting list elements properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, datatables

I have a table with cells that contain list elements, the problem is that when I print the table I lose the list elements and the text becomes very hard to read. see the images.[image]

here is my js to create a datatable, you can just focus on the buttons part.

```
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    qxGenerateDataTables();

});

function qxGenerateDataTables() {
    $("table.dataTable:not(table.dataTableProcessed)").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var paganation = !$this.hasClass("no-pagination");
        var title = $this.attr ("data-file-name");
        var excel= !$this.hasClass("no-excel");
        var table = $this.DataTable({
            "bPaginate": paganation,
            "bSort": true,
            stateSave: true,
            ordering : true,
            searching: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            columnDefs : [ {
                orderable : false,
                targets : "no-sort"
            } ]
        ,
        dom:'B<"wrapper"iftlp>',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i style="font-size:24px;color:#337ab7" class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-2x"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Excel',
                title:  title,
                customize: function( xlsx ) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    $('row:first c', sheet).attr( 's', '55' );

                }
            }, 
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: '<i style="font-size:24px;color:#337ab7" class="fa fa fa-print fa-2x"></i>'
            }
        ]

        });
        table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#qxDatatable_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );

        //Surround the table with an outer div, to have the horizontal scroll working properly.
        var wrapperDiv = $("<div>", {style:"overflow:auto; width: 100%;"});
        $this.before(wrapperDiv);
        wrapperDiv.append($this);
        //Mark this table as processed.
        $this.addClass('dataTableProcessed');
        //Just hide the button for now until we find a better way.
        if (!excel){
            $('.fa-file-excel-o').css( 'display', 'none' );
        }

        //Hide the table info if pagination is disabled...
        if (!paganation){
            $('.dataTables_info').css( 'display', 'none' );
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Your code seems OK. 
If you can give us a complete working jsfiddle, it will help us understand the possible css conflicts for instance...

Comment: Ok let me prepare it

Comment: @Pierre http://jsfiddle.net/quakecore/ws40x8oq/5/ and I can't show the print button there for some reason can you help?

Comment: is missing the 2 js for the buttons : https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js and the css https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
 i suppose

Comment: No I am sure I added them, and here is another try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/quakecore/ebRXw/7953/

Comment: Here is a working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pierre_noel/frqj4ndp/3/

Comment: Thanks, now as you can see after printing, the list order is lost and I really would love to maintain that

Comment: I see now the problem :-) Not sure there is a solution, see : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31081/datatables-print-view-doesnt-maintain-display-formatting-css  Datatable seems to remove all the html; i think the easiest would be to create a custom button calling a JS code from you that will print a HTML div containing an html table created by you from datatable data...can be easier than "fix" the datatable code that strips out your custom html code in the cells...

Comment: i'm taking a loot at https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.js ...

Comment: I already took a look couldn't figure out what to change though.

Comment: i've created a custom my_print.js from buttons.print.js... if you do a console.log(data); after var data = dt.buttons.exportData(
$.extend( {decodeEntities: true}, config.exportOptions ) // XSS protection); you see that the html code is removed...

Comment: Found the solution ;-) 
So 1) you take https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.js and create your own print.js file , 2) instead of displaying <li> and </li>, you display [li] and [/li] ...like this Datatable won't remove this.... 3) in your print.js code you change the line str += '<'+tag+' '+classAttr+'>'+dataOut+'</'+tag+'>'; by dataOut = dataOut.replace("[li]","<li>");; dataOut = dataOut.replace("[/li]","</li>"); str += '<'+tag+' '+classAttr+'>'+dataOut+'</'+tag+'>';

Comment: Please share it in an answer, you deserve a thumps up.

Comment: i'm doing this ! ;-)

Comment: done ! thanks in advance for your thumbup and check/validate the answer if it's convenient for you ;-) And Happy new year ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that all that was needed to be done is to turn off the `scriptHtml` in the export options. Figured it out after looking at [how the script works](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.js)

Now my export button JS looks like this:

```
    {
     extend: 'print',
     text: '<i style="font-size:24px;color:#337ab7" class="fa fa fa-print fa-2x"></i>',
     exportOptions: 
      {
            stripHtml: false
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, i tried this out, but it doesnt seem work for me :" the print preview doesnt render it , but the real table page works fine

Answer (score 2):

As Datatable code seems to remove the HTML code when printing, the solution is to remove your html tags (ie `<li>`) by [li] and [/li]

Then :

1. you take https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.js and create your own print.js file
2. instead of displaying `<li>` and `</li>`, you display [li] and [/li] ...like this Datatable won't remove this
3. in your print.js code you change the line `str += '<'+tag+' '+classAttr+'>'+dataOut+'</'+tag+'>';`

by

`dataOut = dataOut.replace("[li]","<li>");`

`dataOut = dataOut.replace("[/li]","</li>");`

`str += '<'+tag+' '+classAttr+'>'+dataOut+'</'+tag+'>';`

4. you have finally to add a custom renderer in your cells for replacing [li] and [/li] by `<li>` and `</li>`

And it's done ! ;-)

And happy new year (near to 2h AM in France ;-) ) !!

Comment: will give it a try tomorrw :)

Comment: Good night! :-)